# .htacces - RewriteRule with 2 rules

Tags: php, .htaccess, friendly-url

I have the Query String:

```
/index.php?abrir=usuario&id=1&pagina=1
```

So, i need to change to:

/usuario/1/1

I create the code:

```
RewriteRule ^([^-]+)/$ /index.php?abrir=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

How I can modified that? Because I only can get:

```
/usuario&id=1&pagina=1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For other links, just add a line above it:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?abrir=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?abrir=$1&id=$2&pagina=$3
```

Comment: Good! But I have others links like only /index.php?abrir=notices how I resolve it? :x

Comment: I need a problem now with images :x Is possible I create a exception? I have a image-link like:

/data_livro/capa_livro/af58e898f91509b.jpg

and not load.. :x the location is correct...

Comment: You should post another question if that's the case

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841616/exception-with-htaccess-image-broken thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your id and pagina arguments are digits you can use this rule :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(\d*)/(\d*)$ index.php?abrir=$1&id=$2&pagina=$3
```