# Exception with .htaccess (image broken)

Tags: .htaccess, friendly-url

I'm using:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?abrir=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?abrir=$1&id=$2&pagina=$3
```

and I have the image link:

> /data_livro/capa_livro/af58e898f91509b.jpg

How I can add a exception for show the image? Its broke...

My full .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?abrir=$1
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?abrir=$1&id=$2&pagina=$3

RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]

ErrorDocument 400 index.php
ErrorDocument 401 index.php
ErrorDocument 403 index.php
ErrorDocument 404 index.php
ErrorDocument 504 index.php
ErrorDocument 505 index.php
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that using `.*` in a rewrite rule is too general.  I tend to use more specific character classes:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?abrir=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?abrir=$1&id=$2&pagina=$3
```

This doesn't rewrite any request with a dot in it, so specific file names (/styles/my.css, /images/example.jpg) get ignored.  Also, I like to add `/?` to allow an optional trailing slash, but that's a personal preference :-).

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding this correctly, ading the following ahead of your RewriteRules should solve the problem:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

However, I'd also suggest modifying your RewriteRules to look like:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?abrir=$1
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?abrir=$1&id=$2&pagina=$3
```

Comment: Perhaps try removing the last RewriteRule you have there (the image file extension one). The RewriteRules/RewriteCond I've listed work fine on my server the way you want, so I'm not sure why they wouldn't on yours. Also, try making sure you have FollowSymLinks on. (You can do that by adding `Options +FollowSymLinks` to your .htaccess file.)